# Javascript : Alert Box dismissed when tabs switched

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert

**How not to allow Alert Box to be dismissed when tabs switched.**

Using `alert("Test");` on Google Chrome, when you switch tabs, the alert dialog box disappears, and when you're back on the same tab you have full access.

What I want is to do the same thing as **stackoverflow** website when you create a question and try to close the tab, there's a dialog box that pops up that doesn't allow you to go anywhere until you choose between (**Leave** or **Stay**).

IE and Firefox work differently, I mean block the tab when using `alert("Test");` statement but Google Chrome doesn't block.

I sent a bug report to Google but they replied to me that : 
**This is working as intended, see  [Issue 629964](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=629964).
It's not a security bug; a user could make the dialog box disappear with developer tools or myriad other tricks as well.**

Comment: _"It's not a security bug"_ --- there you go. Chrome devs are giving the user the final say, which in my opinion is the better choice.

Comment: Chrome devs are human like you and me and are not **THAT** special !!!  So do not praise so much their reply.
Why **IE** and **Firefox** are behaving differently concerning the same thing?? (Javascript **alert()** function) and when it's got the name **"Dialog Box"**, it's supposed to behave like a real dialog box that we find in all programming language but it **DOES NOT** !!!  Anyway, It's 21st Century, one takes only action when the issue becomes threatening website security...after many website have already been compromised.  New World we've built !!!

Comment: What does this have to do with security? The Chrome behaviour is to stop websites holding browsers hostage. -- I may praise what ever reply I see fit. -- Please do not shout. -- The language JavaScript does not have "dialog box". It is instead a WebAPI defined by the HTML standard.

Comment: Maybe someone like @deceze has more to say on the subject?

Comment: Very good idea but only works **in one way** !!! Trying to stop Expert/Guru/Hackers holding browsers hostage and Let Newbies easily in without any effort !   **lot of laughs...** I'm not shouting, bold & uppercase is merely to emphasize some points.  Have a good day !

Comment: The truth is I prefer IE & Firefox idea to block the tab until one does click on it like a real dialog box. I don't like the current Google Chrome idea.  So anyway, How do I make the dialog box standing up until a user click on it?  similar to the one for **stackoverflow** as explained on my first post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get around this issue by calling my javascript alert in an iframe

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that this appears to have reached a compromise; current (Version 110.0.5481.104 (Official Build) (64-bit)) shows `alert()` and `confirm()` on the tab, but do not prevent going to another tab.
When user returns to the original tab - the message box is still there waiting for them.
So this allows persistence, without "hijacking the browser". :)

Comment: hmmm... I'm not seeing what you report on Version 114.0.5735.90 (Official Build) (arm64)