# Why does alert box closes automatically on Chrome tab (window) change?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert

Whenever a normal alert box displays on a Chrome tab, it disappears when you switch the tab (ok is triggered automatically). Not the same behaviour on Firefox. I am wondering why? Didn't find any answers... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate? [Javascript : Alert Box dismissed when tabs switched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161786/javascript-alert-box-dismissed-when-tabs-switched)

**From Google: "This is working as intended, see Issue 629964 . It's not a security bug; a user could make the dialog box disappear with developer tools or myriad other tricks as well.**"