# Javascript confirm closes instantly in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, confirm, window.location

This code is working correctly in firefox and IE but in chrome the javascript confirm window displays for just a second and instantly closes (and runs the else statement sending someone away from the page)

What is wrong with this code in Chrome?

```js
var alerted = '';

if (alerted != 'yes') {
  if (confirm("Accept?")) {
    localStorage.setItem('alerted', 'yes');
    //box.checked = true;
  }
  else {
    window.location.assign('https://www.example.com/previous-page/');
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure cuz is working with me just in yes give no box declare

Comment: Works fine for me in a current Chrome (67.0.something) on Win 10 as well.

Comment: Using Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) on an x64 windows system results in a confirmation box that awaits my input.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy) may be useful. Its how chrome handles `confirm`'s in modern browsers. Notably the bit about how popups on non focused tabs close instantly. May not apply but worth noting. Either way `confirms/prompts/alerts` etc should be avoided.

Comment: Please test HERE, and add the code that causes your issue perhaps. In this context it appears to not be reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavioral for Google Chrome:
[Javascript : Alert Box dismissed when tabs switched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161786/javascript-alert-box-dismissed-when-tabs-switched). Each browser handles the `confirm()` dialog differently.

When you change the location of the window, the alert immediately dismisses. I would recommend writing your confirmation as an HTML node with a `<button>` element. This would prevent any discrepancies between different browsers.